# IE7 and Scriptaculous Autocompleter running out of memory

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, prototypejs, scriptaculous

In IE7 only, I'm getting a weird out of memory error when I run my Autocompleter.Local. The content downloaded is around 1 MB in terms, but it's done in the background (in a JSON file).

```
function create_listeners() {
 jQuery('.auto_complete_field').each(function() {
   var terms_id = 'terms_' + jQuery(this).attr('id');
   jQuery(this).after('<div class="auto_complete" id="' + terms_id + '"></div>');
//   jQuery(this).attr('value', 'test');
   new Autocompleter.Local(jQuery(this).attr('id'),terms_id, terms, {fullSearch:false, frequency:0, minChars:1});
 })
}
```

Anyone have any idea why this would affect IE 6/7 only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *appears* that IE7 has a 1 MB blob size limit on variables, and that's what we were running into here.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use [dynaTrace Ajax Edition](http://ajax.dynatrace.com) to find the bottleneck.